# get the same word in file only 1 word if it have many word are the same using PHP

Tags: php, file

I want to read data from text file and group for some data are the same.I have code as below:

```
$PMTA_DATE = date("Y-m-d");
            $PMTA_FILE = file_get_contents("../stats_domain_emetteur_recepteur.affinitead.net.".$PMTA_DATE.".txt");
            $lineFromText = explode("\n", $PMTA_FILE);
            $result = array();
            $cate = "";
            $total ="";
            $fail = "";
            $mailSuc = "";
            $title = "";
            foreach($lineFromText as $line){                    
                    $words = explode(";",$line);
                    echo $words[5];
                    echo "<br>";
                     if($title == ""){
                         $title = $words[0];
                     }

                     $cate .= ','."'$words[6]'";
                     $total .= ','.$words[7];
                     $fail .= ','.$words[8];
                     $mailSuc .= ','.((int)$words[7] - (int)$words[8]);                         

     }
```

**In file data:**

```
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;boulevard-des-ventes.com;hotmail.fr;150116;90753;60.45
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;boulevard-des-ventes.com;hotmail.com;108478;65766;60.62
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;boulevard-des-ventes.com;free.fr;81431;97;.11
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;boulevard-des-ventes.com;wanadoo.fr;77786;15;.01
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;boulevard-des-ventes.com;gmail.com;77325;1;0
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;boulevard-des-ventes.com;orange.fr;44768;13;.02
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;boulevard-des-ventes.com;laposte.net;33844;16;.04
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;boulevard-des-ventes.com;neuf.fr;29918;26;.08
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;boulevard-des-ventes.com;yahoo.fr;23232;1;0
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;friendcorp.fr;yahoo.fr;21073;2;0
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;boulevard-des-ventes.com;voila.fr;19692;3;.01
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;messengear.fr;free.fr;18234;5;.02
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;friendcorp.fr;free.fr;17658;12;.06
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;lebuzzdesbonsplans.com;yahoo.fr;15856;103;.64
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;cwlunit.com;laposte.net;13463;1;0
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;boulevard-des-ventes.com;msn.com;12044;7222;59.96
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;boulevard-des-ventes.com;live.fr;11491;6983;60.76
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;boulevard-des-ventes.com;aliceadsl.fr;11145;17;.15
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;cwlunit.com;sfr.fr;11135;1;0
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;tendancity.com;yahoo.fr;10631;0;0
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;boulevard-des-ventes.com;sfr.fr;9878;1;.01
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;boulevard-des-ventes.com;club-internet.fr;9868;4;.04
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;friendcorp.fr;wanadoo.fr;9533;0;0
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;boulevard-des-ventes.com;aol.com;9253;7729;83.52
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;lebuzzdesbonsplans.com;hotmail.com;8656;252;2.91
2012-12-19-0830;affinitead.net;1409462;231830;16.44;messengear.fr;laposte.net;8616;1;.01
```

as you see have some data are the same like `boulevard-des-ventes.com` it has many time so I don't want that.I want take it only 1 if it has many time.

This is the output I need:

```
boulevard-des-ventes.com        hotmail.fr  150116
                                hotmail.com 108478
                                free.fr      81431
                                ..................
                                ..................
                                ..................
friendcorp.fr                   yahoo.fr    21073
                                free.fr      17658
cwlunit.com                     laposte.net  13463
                                sfr.fr       11135
                                ..................
                                ..................
                                ..................
..................................................
..................................................
..................................................
```

Comment: the lines are not identical. so which one do you want to have when there is the same domain names? first occurence? last? can you show the result you want?

Comment: This what I want : http://www.unitead.pro/kama/stats/pmta/Emetteur_Recepteur/Ineed.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an associative array to remember which domains you've already processed, and skip to the next line when you get a duplicate.

```
$domains_seen = array();
foreach($lineFromText as $line){
  $words = explode(";",$line);
  $domain = $words[5];
  if array_key_exists($domain, $domains_seen) {
    continue;
  }
  $domains_seen[$domain] = true;
  ...
}
```